# pf, Sense of Humour?

Tags: riddle

Guess who I am:

> I connect people with each other.
>
> I am open for everyone
>
> and though, at the same time, only few can get access.
>
> It's good to have me... let's you be more relaxed.
>
> You can use me to get private with someone
>
> If you get this private, nobody will know that you are you. Everybody will just see the other one.
>
> At the same time, I am the endpoint of this privateness.
>
> I don't have to be there physically, though I can.
>
> My life consists out of rules - but that's why I am here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you

> A router? More specific a firewalling / packet filtering (pf) one connecting a private network with the Internet (doing NAT)? Let's say pfSense then.

?

Comment: Very Good direction! Though you cannot explain all credentials!

Comment: @asparagus: Actually I think everything you put in yellow fits very well. If i  had seen anything that wouldn't fit in my opinion, I'd have said so. Only thing i didn't catch is the sense of humour from the title. So I am at a loss here. Could you please hint me at which credential(s) you think it doesn't fit?

Comment: "If you get this private, nobody will know that you are you. Everybody will just see the other one"!      (Installing only a router doesn't fulfill the task, that you seem as if you were someone different)

Comment: If you don't understand the title, chances are you won't get the answer... Should've known that I shouldn't dig that deep.

Comment: @asparagus: I added a part to the answer that in my opinion fits fine to the "private" thing you mention. But I will be musing about the title a bit.

Comment: Is the title a reference to [pfSense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PfSense)?

Comment: Would have been my next question, too:-) Does the title mean you are looking for a specific one? I would probably suggest a different one.

Comment: @ngn yeah, that's it! Was it "to deep"?

Comment: No, too specific for too broad a thing. pf and sense are not closely tied to pfSense, those are rather generic firewalling terms. Also you are mixing firewalling and routing, which leads away from that specific product. - BTW, I updated my answer

Comment: Ok thanks, yes!
I thought pfSense would fit because it is: A router, a firewall, "open for everyone" (open source) and is able to establish VPNs.

Comment: OK, since you deleted the "no" from the title, I get that hint a bit better. Also I quickly looked up the product range and can agree that routing is a part of the whole package.

Comment: @asparagus It was only a few minutes of pondering and a couple of duckduckgo searches deep, however it was very pleasant to see a reference to BSD here :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you...

> **The internet**?

I connect people with each other.

> The internet connects people from around the world

I am open for everyone

> Anyone with access to it can use it freely

and though, at the same time, only few can get access.

> Not everyone can afford internet access

It's good to have me... let's you be more relaxed.

> Through the internet you can do all sorts of relaxing activities, such as chatting, listening to music, playing games, etc.

You can use me to get private with someone

> You can have private messages with people and not have them publicly available

If you get this private, nobody will know that you are you. Everybody will just see the other one.

> One of the key aspects of the internet is anonymity

At the same time, I am the endpoint of this privateness.

> People who expose themselves on the internet basically give up their private lives to the rest of the world.

I don't have to be there physically, though I can.

> You can connect wirelessly or via cables

My life consists out of rules - but I am made for them.

> Internet protocols?

Comment: Nice try, good direction - but not what I am! Added one more hint in my description!